# PHP unknown error verify regististration

Tags: php, web

I don't know whats wrong, but I'm not a PHP expert. Can anyone help me?

My PHP code:

```
session_start()
$verify = $_SESSION["verify"];
include '../register.php';
$user = strtolower($_POST["name"]);
$rdm = rand(1000,9999);
$verifylink = "https://darkcrafting.net/verify/";
```

I'm including this to another site but this doesn't work.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown error"? Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1):

You missed ; after session_start()

```
session_start();
```